# multidimensional array is being sorted as string rather than by value

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort the following two dimensional array in a descending order by the first column:

```
wordsAndCount = [[0,"string"],[4,"string"],[31,"string"],[1,"string"],[3,"string"]];
wordsAndCount.sort();
wordsAndCount.reverse();
```

For some reason, JavaScript is treating the first column as a string rather than an integer, returning the following output:

```
[4,"string"],[31,"string"],[3,"string"],[1,"string"],[0,"string"]
```

When the desired output should be:

```
[31,"string"],[4,"string"],[3,"string"],[1,"string"],[0,"string"]
```

What's causing JS to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript is treating the whole element as a string, not just the first element.

[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), without any sort function specified, will call `toString()` on each element it looks at. Calling `toString()` on elements like yours, in all JavaScript engines I know, will give values like `"[0,\"string\"]"`

You should specifiy your own sorter function to fix this:

```
wordsAndCount.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[0] - a[0];
});
```

There'll also be no need to use `reverse()` then.

For more info, see the [MDC documentation on `sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: You probably want `b[0]-a[0]` to eliminate the `reverse` call.

Comment: @Shmiddty: Mental maths failing me. Was about to do a fiddle to check I wasn't wrong ;).

Comment: That works! however I think u should reverse the order of `a[0] - b[0]` to get a *descending* order, right?

Comment: @WebDeskIL: You're right yeah; already fixed. Scary I've got a maths exam tomorrow morning, right? :P

Comment: Heh. The rapidly changing internet.

Answer (score 1):

How are you expecting JavaScript to sort your array?  From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> **Syntax**
>
> array.sort([compareFunction])
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *compareFunction* Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If
>   omitted, the array is sorted lexicographically (in dictionary order) according to the string conversion of each element.

You need to *tell* JS how to sort that array, otherwise as promised it will sort it lexicographically (which is almost certainly not what you're after)